Why did Rita and Cage run out from HQ after getting Dr. Carter's machine?
In Edge of Tomorrow (2014), after Rita and Cage got the machine of Dr. Carter from the colonel, why did they not use it immediately in the office?
After the vision, once Cage knows the location of the Omega, Rita just shoots Cage, and they could avoid the misery of the escape.

Because they need to take the machine with them? It needs a live mimic to work.

An in-universe explanation is that in the heat of the moment, and under pressure, they forgot that the most logical thing to do would be to kill themselves so as to restart the day over with the newfound knowledge of the Omega's location: perhaps, like all of us, they didn't want to die. Alternatively, perhaps Cage was worried that he would not have enough time or evidence to convince Rita and/or Carter of the Omega's location if they restarted the day - perhaps he had tried this already in a previous cycle and found it hadn't worked.
Alternatively, perhaps, unbeknownst to us, it was the best course of action: remember that Rita has already been to see General Brigham "hundreds of times", with the result being "psych ward...dissection". Rita knew that medical analysis of this kind might involve blood transfusion and loss of the power, so removing themselves from the General's office as soon as possible was a high priority.
In any case, "making mistakes" is an often overlooked theme in the movie: the ultimate lesson of the film is that it is almost impossible to make it through even one day of life without making a mistake, let alone a day of life in the heat of battle. It's the concept of making mistakes in battle that also underpins the plot of "The Defence of Duffer's Drift" (1904), a short novel from 1904 with a very similar plotline to Edge of Tomorrow. Our heroes make other fundamental mistakes as the film progresses: for example, Rita forgets to unhook the trailer; Cage doesn't reset the day when he discovered the Mimic decoy at the dam. In the case of leaving Brigham's office, our heroes appeared to make a fundamental mistake, but perhaps this is the point of the film.
